# How can I retrieve the values in a column that are not contained in another column in google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, duplicates, google-sheets-formula

I have two columns in a google sheet and want to retrieve the values of one of the columns that are not in the other column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(A:A; NOT(COUNTIF(B:B; A:A)))
```

[image]