# Filter out names that are not in the grouped sheet - Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheets. One is containing names that have been grouped. The other contains ungrouped names. Now, there are some names in the ungrouped that do not appear in the grouped which means some names are missing from the grouped sheet. I need to filter out which names are not in the grouped sheets to come out in a column. Any help is appreciated. The link is below.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nTO3Y3uktKKU-GgHuXYoyBuYz0zzGXr6ygBhFNDA2_o/edit?usp=sharing

And yes, I have tried many of the answers here already, they are not working for me.

[How can I retrieve the values in a column that are not contained in another column in google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58701108/how-can-i-retrieve-the-values-in-a-column-that-are-not-contained-in-another-colu)

This came close but its for column. I'm checking the whole sheet.

I have tried **VLOOKUP** [image: A screenshot of VLOOKUP]
I even tried this custom functions, they are all not working or I'm doing it wrongly.

What I expect to happen is:
A column containing names that are in the sheet 2 but not in sheet one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this out:

```
=filter(A:A,iserror(xmatch(A:A,(tocol(choosecols('Sheet 1'!B4:R48,sequence(1,9,1,2)),1)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.

These returns the names already on sheet 1 already. I wish it will bring those are not on the sheet 1.

Thanks again

Comment: I searched for around 10 names from the output in sheet 1 and cant seem to find them. Can you maybe highlight the names in your sample sheet which names are found in the formula result that are also in sheet 1; that would help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you so much. The error is from the Sheet 1. Some of the names are not written properly in Sheet 1, so the formular couldn't find it. Thank you so much for your help. Your answer works!

Comment: yeah I can see there' one `Emmanuel Sefah` with two spaces in b/w first and second name of sheet 1 and just single space in sheet 2